# How to use async/await in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I'm new in ES7

I want to use async/await in Vue.js

Here is my code

```
created (){
    this.getA()
    console.log(2)
    this.getB() 
},
methods : {
    getA (){
        console.log(1)
    },
    getB (){
        console.log(3)
    }
}
```

It returns

```
1
2
3
```

But when I use it with axios, then

```
created (){
    this.getA()
    console.log(2)
    this.getB() 
},
methods : {
    getA (){
        $axios.post(`/getA`,params){
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(1)
        })
    },
    getB (){
        console.log(3)
    }
}
```

It returns

```
2
3
1
```

So I want to add async/await in that code.

How can I use async/await?

I tried

```
async created (){
    await this.getA()
    console.log(2)
    await this.getB() 
},
methods : {
    getA (){
        $axios.post(`/getA`,params){
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(1)
        })
    },
    getB (){
        console.log(3)
    }
}
```

It returns same result.

Comment: `getA` doesn't return the promise.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You have to use either `then` or `await` not both as shown below:

If using `then`

```
created () {
    this.getA().then((result) => {
            console.log(1)
            console.log(2)
            this.getB()
        })
},
methods : {
    getA () {
        return $axios.post(`/getA`,params);
    },
    getB (){
        console.log(3)
    }
}
```

If using `await`

```
async created (){
    await this.getA()
    console.log(1)
    console.log(2)
    this.getB() 
},
methods : {
    getA : async() => {
        return $axios.post(`/getA`,params);
    },
    getB : () => {
        console.log(3)
    }
}
```

Note that while calling getB() you don't need `then` or `await` since it is not asynchronous

Comment: since `getB` is not asynchronous, then what is the use of `async` for `getB` ?

Answer (score 15):

Unlike what @thanthu said, you can use both then and await.
In your first post you only missed to add `return` in the `getA` method:

```
async created (){
    await this.getA()
    console.log(2)
    await this.getB() 
},
methods : {
    getA() {
        return $axios
            .post(`/getA`,params){
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(1)
            });
    },
    getB() { 
        console.log(3)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can. But should you? one day you will find yourself in the middle of `try-catch` and `.catch(err => {console.log(err)}) ` blocks, with tons of `async-await` and `.then` and `.all` instructions.

It could be the second most difficult challenge for a gentleman. Of course, after an attempt to give birth to a baby. For women - the most difficult one.

Comment: it still feels like the way to go, you are _awaiting_ for a promise that ends when `console.log(1)` run

Answer (score 8):

**Vuejs**, example with **Axios** API request. more details between the code

```
  methods: {
    async getA(data, type) {
      console.log("This is a API calls, that the response time is vary.");

      const result = await this.getSources();
      
      console.log("Do what you want after completing the prev job.");
    },
    getSources() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {

        // Here the point is the resolve that you should resolve('something');.
        this.axios
          .get("/api/sources")
          .then((resp) => {
            this.sources = resp.data;
            resolve('resolved');
          })
          .catch(() => {
            resolve('rejected');
          });
      });
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
async created (){
    let resultFromgetA = await this.getA()
    console.log(2)
    await this.getB() 
},
methods : {
    getA :() =>{
        return $axios.post(`/getA`,params);
    },
    getB : async() =>{
        //use await key with async calls
        console.log(3)
    }
}
```

Comment: adding async to created lifecycle method made it work for me while having a chained promises procedure.