# VueJS and nested v-for: How to get endpoint data through each loop?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

I am using VUEJS to build a single page application. I have a single file component that gets some data from an API (using Axios) and uses `v-for` to render out a list like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="division in divisions" :key="division.id_PK">
        {{ division.c6code }} - XXX
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

  props: {
    country: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
data() {
    return {
      divisions: [],
    },
methods: {
    async getDivisions() {
      const divisions = await APIService.getDivisions(
        this.country.igpeSID_FK
      )
      this.divisions = divisions
    },
}
```

An example of the API data source looks like `/getDivisions/800001`:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "id_PK": 205891,
      "igpeSID_FK": 800001,
      "c6code": "AB-CDE"
    },
    {
      "id_PK": 205890,
      "igpeSID_FK": 800001,
      "c6code": "FG-HIJ"
    },
    {
      "id_PK": 205889,
      "igpeSID_FK": 800001,
      "c6code": "KL-MNO"
    },
    {
      "id_PK": 205888,
      "igpeSID_FK": 800001,
      "c6code": "PQ-RST"
    },
    {
      "id_PK": 205887,
      "igpeSID_FK": 800001,
      "c6code": "WX-YZA"
    }
  ]
}
```

The rendered UI looks like so:

[image]

Now, there is another API endpoint that contains additional data that I need to put in place of the "XXX" placeholder shown above. That additional data source has a property called `name` and contains the actual division name which was not included in the `/getDivisions` API (only the associated property `id_PK` is provided).

Question: How can I get this name for each division?

An example of this endpoint that contains the additional data is: `/getDivisionNameById/{id_PK}` where `id_PK` is the parameter I need to pass to it from the getDivisions data shown above. So, for example, if I pass `205891` to the `/getDivisionNameById/205891` I get back data that looks like so:

**Example `/getDivisionNamesById/205891`:**

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "P_uniqueID": 16919,
      "isoGeoDivisionEntry_FK": 205891,
      "name": "ZABUL",
      "lang": "fa"
    },
    {
      "P_uniqueID": 16918,
      "isoGeoDivisionEntry_FK": 205891,
      "name": "ZABUL",
      "lang": "ps"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am thinking that I need to create a function that somehow creates a new array of names that I could then loop through in yet another `v-for` in my original template like so:

```
<li v-for="division in divisions" :key="division.id_PK">
        {{ division.c6code }} - <span v-for="divName in divisionNames" :key="division.id_PK">{{divName.name}}</span>
      </li>

async getDivisionNameById(id_PK) {
    const name = await APIService.getDivisionNameById(id_PK)
    this.divNames.push(name)
    
}
```

Obviously, I don't know what I am doing there...

Codesandbox with data:

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-wind-21w35?file=/src/getDivisionNamesById.json

Comment: replace the content inside the li with a component, i.e `<division-info :pk="division.id_PK"/>` then inside the component do another API query lookup, its not ideal to do a bunch of querys but at least if you abstract it will lazyload

Comment: Good reminder, thx

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Thanks so much. This was the simple solution for me!

Answer (score 1):

You have to query the data first before rendering the content.
You could fetch all the data in onMounted hook.

Comment: Thanks, it was a partial solution to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a good place for a computed property.
Edit this example as needed depending on how you call your APIs.

You could call both API endpoints in the [mounted lifecycle-hook](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#mounted) of the component. Included this with a simple timeout to simulate the data coming in at different times.

About the secondary API call(s) where you get the name-data: As you've already said, loop through the IDs and make the API calls. In this case you'd need to wait for the result of your first API call and then use those ID's it returns to make the second API call(s). Maybe this will help you with the await/asyc/then stuff:
[How to use async/await in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955426/how-to-use-async-await-in-vue-js)

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(division, index) in fullList" :key="index">
        {{ division }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import divisions from "@/getDivisionsEntries.json";
import divisionNames from "@/getDivisionNamesById.json";
export default {
  name: "DivisionsList",
  data() {
    return {
      divisions: divisions.data,
      divisionNames: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.divisions = divisions.data;
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.divisionNames = divisionNames.data;
    }, 3000);
  },
  computed: {
    fullList: function () {
      let combinedArr = [];
      for (var divi of this.divisions) {
        var divNameData = this.divisionNames?.find(
          (x) => x.isoGeoDivisionEntry_FK === divi.id_PK
        );
        if (divNameData !== undefined) {
          combinedArr.push(`${divi.c6code} - ${divNameData.name}`);
        }
      }
      return combinedArr;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent. Let me review and get back to you!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I ended up using another method BUT your answer helped me better understand the problem!