# Async / Await method in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await, vue-component

I have this rather simple `Vue` component (stripped of unnecessary parts):

```
Vue.component('equipment-tree', {
    data(){
        return {
            tree: [],
    }
},
template: `
    <template>
        <div id="equipment_tree"></div>
    </template>`,
mounted: function(){
    this.getTreeView()
    console.log('4. TREE LOADED AND VISIBLE');;
},
methods: {
    setUpTree(){
        $("#equipment_tree").jstree("destroy");
        $('#equipment_tree').jstree({ 
            core : {
                data : this.tree,
                multiple: false,
                themes: { 
                    dots: true
                }
            },
        });
        console.log("2. TREE SET UP")
    },
    getTreeView(){
        fetch("myurl /*just a URL */", 
            {
                method: 'GET',
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log('1. GOT DATA');
                this.tree = JSON.parse(data.tree);
                this.setUpTree();
                console.log('3. SET UP COMPLETE');
            })
        }
    }
})
```

On mount, I call the method `getTreeView()` that gets the data from the database, saves it in the variable `tree`, and then calls `setUpTree()` which creates a tree using the `jstree` library. When I run it in the log I see

```
4. TREE LOADED AND VISIBLE
1. GOT DATA
2. TREE SET UP
3. SET UP COMPLETE
```

that is, the flow continues after the call to `getTreeView()`. Now, what if I want to wait until `getTreeView()` finishes so that the log `4. TREE LOADED AND VISIBLE` gets actually printed last?

I tried with `async/await` as follows: I changed

```
mounted: function(){
        this.getTreeView()
        console.log('4. TREE LOADED AND VISIBLE');;
    }
```

into

```
mounted: async function(){
        await Promise.resolve(this.getTreeView());
        console.log('4. TREE LOADED AND VISIBLE');
    }
```

but I got the same result as before. Same if following the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54955426/5060614).
How can I wait for the method `getTreeView()` to finish?

Please, note that this is a reduced example because I want to understand how it works, not just because the order of log matters.

Comment: Is there any reason not to make gettreeview asynchronous so you can await it directly?

Comment: This is not a vue thing this is how async code works. Your function getTreeView is dealing with promises, it executes right away but the side effects it results in happen when the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to wait for method too:

```
async getTreeView(){
    await fetch("myurl /*just a URL */", 
        {
            method: 'GET',
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('1. GOT DATA');
            this.tree = JSON.parse(data.tree);
            this.setUpTree();
            console.log('3. SET UP COMPLETE');
        })
    }
}
```

in mounted hook:

```
async mounted(){
    await this.getTreeView();
    console.log('4. TREE LOADED AND VISIBLE');
}
```

Comment: Now this works! But I don't get it at first: why the "double await"? Why the `await` on `getTreeView()` in `mounted` is not enough? Thanks

Comment: Because you need to wait till method resolve, so other lines want execute till then